# Get all possible results for a RegEx pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use the `RegEx` class in C# in order to solve the fallowing problem:

Given a `RegEx` pattern, say `"RK[0-2]{2}"`, return a list that contains all the strings that match the pattern, *e.g.* `[RK00, R01, RK02, RK10, RK11, RK12, RK20, RK21, RK22]`.

Looking at the `RegEx` documentation, it seems it can only tell if a given string match a patter or find all the occurrences of a pattern in a string. But I haven't found where a `RegEx` can generate strings out of input pattern.

Comment: And what should it generate for the regex `.*` ?

Comment: What would be the result of `.*`?

Comment: as written (without a ^ at the beginning and a $ at the end) RK[0-2]{2} too would generate an infinite set. It would also match "helloRK01world".

Comment: You'd be better off doing this in a simple `for` loop.  `RegEx` isn't designed for this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, they can't. Regexes are meant to match input strings, not generate them; trying to generate possible input strings could also become infinitely complex. Take, for instance, the following Regex

```
[\s\S]*
```

This will match literally any string. Thus, it would generate an effectively infinite result set.

IF you want to generate possible strings, you're going to be writing it from the ground up, and I would seriously question why you're doing so. This smells like an X/Y problem.

Comment: That does not match every string... That only matches strings made of literal periods and spaces...

Comment: @iismathwizard In C# regexes, as the question is tagged, the `.` character matches any single character except newlines. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#

Comment: `[.\s]*` matches zero or more whitespaces or literal period symbols. `(?s).*` will match anything.

Comment: @stribizhev that would be `[\.\s]*`

Comment: @Aravol in character groups, the period is interpreted literally.

Comment: @Aravol your regular expression **is** wrong. Please fix it. I'm sure you can write a C# program that proves it. I just did.

Comment: https://ideone.com/ZEx4Oa is a demonstration of `[.]` in a regular expression. Of note is that I used `+` instead of `*` to avoid matching zero of the symbol.

Comment: This answer is correct that `[.\s]*` matches literally any string, though for the wrong reason. That's because it allows for an empty match, and an empty string is a substring of literally any string.

Comment: @Aravol: Out of interest why not use the simpler regex of `.*`? It will match any string still and doesn't have the needless complexity that yours does (as well as being less likely to provoke debates and rollback wars)...

Comment: @Chris `.` does not match newline characters. That's why i edited the answer (multiple times now, due to aravol's pettiness) to `[\s\S]*` which will match all characters. Thanks to stribizhev for teaching that one to me a while ago!

Comment: Both of you, knock it off with the rollback war. Nobody benefits from it at all.

Comment: because `.*` wouldn't match newlines, as originally intended. Said changes have prompted some research, though the main point of unwieldably complicated results stands.

Comment: Yeah, I think matching an infinite number of strings is probably sufficient without needing to hit all strings. ;-)